# How to track changes in indexedDb?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I continued to search, and I heard that IndexedDb does not have an observer. So how can I track the change value? Is it impossible at all? I am currently using IndexedDb using idb-keyval. Do you have any solution? Or should I use a library like localforage instead?

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to use intermediate functions or inject code into the library or patch IndexedDB itself

A version using intermediate code is the most optimal:

```
import { get, set } from "idb-keyval"

const bus = new EventBus<{
  'change:counter': number
}>()
const cast = new BroadcastChannel('watcher-indexeddb')

function mget(name: string): Promise<any> {
  return get(name)
}
async function mset(name: string, value: any): Promise<void> {
  await set(name, value)
  bus.emit(`change:${name}`, value)
  cast.postMessage({ type: `change:${name}`, value })
}

cast.addEventListener("message", event => {
  if (event.data?.type?.startsWith("change"))
    bus.emit(event.data.type, event.data.value)
})

bus.on("change:counter", value => {
  console.log("Counter changed to %s", value)
})

// Usage: mset('counter', 12)
```

Comment: thank you. What is the role of mget?

Comment: Also, what is EventBus? Cannot find name 'EventBus'. I am getting an error.

Comment: This vue.js code looks like Could you please pass me the React code?

Comment: mget is a mapping function in case you need to listen to what a function depends on

EventBus can be anything sorry I didn't specify you can write your own eventBus or the fastest way is to use the `mitt` package `import EventBus from 'mitt'`

this code written in typescript it is not related to vue

Comment: I'm really sorry, but the answer you gave doesn't work in my app. Do you have any other answers?

Comment: I just need to track when indexeddb changes.

Comment: i am wondering how you have implemented my code in your application it will work if you replace the primitive set functions of idb-keyval with the mset function

Comment: Use a broadcast channel as suggested. Keep in mind a common mistake with broadcast channels, if you want to observe channel messages on the same page, you need a second instance of the channel with the same name because the channel does not broadcast to the same instance